# Cannot install library "hashpumpy" because of cpp and exe files not being there

Tags: python, windows, pip

I'd like to install the python library hashpumpy through pip, I run windows 11, have visual studio already installed and run Python 3.10.7.
The first time I tried it, this message showed up:

`Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/`

Cools, so I go to the link and click the install button there, I then download the file, and install the "visual Studio build tools".

I also go to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170) and install the redisiributable there.
I now have this section in my Control Panel>Programs:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bI5EI.png)

and now I try to run `pip install hashpumpy` again. This time, something new, but far more confusing happens:

```
`> pip install hashpumpy
Collecting hashpumpy
  Using cached hashpumpy-1.2.tar.gz (8.3 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Installing collected packages: hashpumpy
  DEPRECATION: hashpumpy is being installed using the legacy 'setup.py install' method, because it does not have a 'pyproject.toml' and the 'wheel' package is not installed. pip 23.1 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to enable the '--use-pep517' option. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8559
  Running setup.py install for hashpumpy ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for hashpumpy did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [17 lines of output]
      running install
      C:\Users\askse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'hashpumpy' extension
      creating build
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\askse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\askse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /EHsc /TpCRC32ex.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\CRC32ex.obj
      CRC32ex.cpp
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\askse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\askse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /EHsc /TpExtender.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\Extender.obj
      Extender.cpp
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\askse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\askse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /EHsc /TpMD4ex.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\MD4ex.obj
      MD4ex.cpp
      C:\Users\askse\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-z_t5kjfm\hashpumpy_bcbe510a90dd43d2a13d062f15235b46\MD4ex.h(5): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/md4.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.34.31933\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> hashpumpy

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.`
```

This looks mystical to me. There are some cpp files that is being looked for, that are not there, and the same goes for a file called `cl.exe`.
I have no clue what this is, or how I should go about fixing it.
Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

I had exact same problem, but I had python 3.11 installed. After switching to python 3.10.4

Comment: add the answer like this, as a comment form